How to translate "leading principal minor"?
It's well established that "principal minor" translates to "menor principal". However, I haven't found a translation for "leading principal minor", which refers to specifically one of the principal minors.
What would be an apropiarte translation?

What does it mean in English? You misspelled appropriate, by the way. It is well establish that principal minor is menor principal? Funny, with all my knowledgte of English, I have zero idea about what you mean.

@Lambie it is a technical term from mathematics.

@mdewey Then, the OP needs to say that and define it. This isn't a math forum. And look, silence.

@Lambie, defining it wouldn't help anything since you either know what I mean (and you know if there is a standard translation for it to Spanish) or you don't. As you said this isn't a math forum. I would like to add that SE sites aren't forums at all. It is indeed funny that, with all your knowledge in English, you missed that it's "Is it well established that [...]?".

Btw, it's under the "matemáticas" tag, so it's implicit that it's a mathematical term.

@Gilgamesh That is a typo from fast typing, obviously. Of course, well established. You either know what it means or etc. Forums, sites, same idea, few would quibble with that. That is not a mistake.  And "with your knowledge of English"|,not in English. Maybe criticizing me is not the best course.  Finally, this is not a translation site really.

@Lambie, I didn't wrote "it means", I wrote "I mean". I wasn't criticizing you, I was pointing out that you also made a typo the same way you did with me. The main characteristic of SE sites is that they aren't forums (also, translations are specifically on-topic).

According to Wikipedia it is menor principal superior. This does make some sense since the submatrix is in the upper left hand corner.

Exactly! In Spanish it is known as "Menor principal superior de una matriz"

Thanks for your answer! I agree that it makes sense and I rather use "superior" than "líder. Since the other answer provided a MSc. Thesis as reference, do you have any (other than Wikipedia) at hand?

@Gilgamesh, just searching "Menor principal superior" in Google you will find multiple notes corresponding to University that talk about that concept.

I'm aware, but also for "menor principal líder" (and I don't know if there is another one). Terminology in Spanish is usually not standardized and I haven't read many linear algebra books to be familiar enough with the current terminology. Maybe they are both sufficiently common, but I'll take "superior"  as it feels more natural.

En álgebra se utiliza "menor principal líder".

Recordemos que un menor principal líder es el determinante de una submatriz principal líder de una matriz A M n (K); K = R o C.

Source docplayer.es
